# Using a dict subclass where dict is expected

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism, xml-rpc

Function A gets an ordinary dict as argument and does some processing.

```
def A(dict):
    ...
    return
```

Now I have a class inherited from ordinary dict class:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)
```

Then can I use MyDict instead of ordinary dict as:

```
my_dict = MyDict()
A(my_dict)
```

?

Specifically, in my case, A does xml-rpc serialization, and error says cannot marshal MyDict.

Comment: As one of the answers says, your question isn't answerable without full details of what's going on in the function. Please show a very small, complete function that we can run by itself ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057778/good-newbie-instructions-for-creating-minimal-complete-bug-examples/4284676#4284676 ) that shows the behaviour which gives you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

That completely depends on what `A()` does. If it merely invokes the mapping protocol then you can use it no problem. If it requires more details about the type passed then there is a chance that it will fail to run correctly.